# NativeScript Slide Item component

Tags: nativescript, slide

In NativeScript is there a slide item component?

This is the kind of control like IOS Mail has for sliding left or right on the email list to expose and select a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are referring to [swipe actions](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/professional-ui-components/ListView/swipe-actions).

```
tns plugin add nativescript-ui-listview
```